# rasm2 doesn't return results or errors when disassembling an intel hex file

Tags: disassembly

I'm running rasm2 to disassemble an intel hex file in Arm M0 32-bit processor format. When I run rasm2 it doesn't return any results or any error messages. It simply just does a CRLF and that is it.

Here is the command with arguments:

rasm2 -a arm -b 32 -f ihex://test.hex -O test.txt

In this case, an output file "test.txt" is created with a 0 byte length.

But no errors either!

I can't include the intel hex file I am using since it is for a customer.

Thanks for any assistance!

Coleman